# start iteration from a specific line in a text file in python

Tags: python

Assume I have a text file (named test.txt) that I have wrote 15 lines into it before in my Python script. Now, I want to append some lines to that file. How can I start iteration from line #16 of test.txt and append some new lines to it in Python?

Comment: when you "open" the file, using the conventional `f = open(FILE)` you should state the method of you are using, in this case, append, so `f = open(FILE, 'a')`

Answer (score 6):

To append at the end of the file, you don't need to "iterate" over it – simply open it in append mode:

```
with open("my_file", "a") as f:
    f.write("another line\n")
```

Iterating over files can be used to *read* them, not to *write* them.

Answer (score 0):

when you "open" the file, using the conventional

```
f = open(FILE)
```

you should state the method of you are using, in this case, append, so

```
f = open(FILE, 'a')
```

Comment: When using `open()` you should also call `f.close()` at the end. The `with` construct shown in the Sven's answer closes the file automatically for you.